# Add global button in CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics

Is there a way to add a new button to ALL PAGES in CRM?
I have tried different ways but in some views, the new button is shown at the end. Im trying to found a way to create a button and place it as first button, to any view, entity and page in CRM. Is this accomplisable?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that out-of-the-box buttons will often take precedence over custom buttons, and the only way to change that would be to hide the out-of-the-box buttons.

I'm assuming you are adding the button via the *Application Ribbon*, correct? (not every single form and grid)

Comment: Yep, Application Ribbon.
I have added 5 buttons in total: For HomePage, for Subgrid, for Forms, for Dashboards and for Grid. I can see the at the beging of every page EXCEPT for activities. In Activities, it is showing the button under the "More activities" elipsis.

Answer (score 0):

You can add items to the "Jewel", (the dropdown from "File" in the top left).  It's not exactly the same as putting it in the ribbon because you have to make an extra click, but it should show up globally.